# Try to rollback anaconda environment but met PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, dependencies, environment

I mistakenly re-installed opencv in anaconda environment. These packages are changed:

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

```
  ca-certificates    conda-forge::ca-certificates-2021.5.3~ --> pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2021.5.25-haa95532_1
  certifi            conda-forge::certifi-2021.5.30-py36ha~ --> pkgs/main::certifi-2021.5.30-py36haa95532_0
  openssl            conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1k-h8ffe710_0 --> pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1k-h2bbff1b_0
```

Then I met this error in my program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\generative_inpainting-master\test.py", line 3, i
n <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I tried to rollback the environment by using anaconda's `conda install –revision 21` but I got

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - conda-forge/win-64::certifi==2021.5.30=py36ha15d459_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::openssl==1.1.1k=h8ffe710_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::ca-certificates==2021.5.30=h5b45459_0
```

I don't know how to fix that. Please help me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the conda-forge channel to your list of channels with this command: `conda config --append channels conda-forge`

Then run the rollback command.